# Same method that uses mono's gdi+ library giving very different results in different machines

Tags: .net, mono, gdi+, jpeg, libjpeg

I've been scratching my head on this one, as I hardly know how to begin to understand the problem in my hands.
The problem is a static method I use (and which I took from some post here in SO), which saves a System.Drawing.Image into a jpeg file on disk, and looks kind of like this:

```
public static void SaveJpeg(string path, Image image, int quality) {
  //create an encoder parameter for the image quality
  EncoderParameter qualityParam = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, quality);
  EncoderParameter compressionParam = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Compression, (long)EncoderValue.CompressionNone);

  // Now in this part there is some code which gets the jpeg ImageCodecInfo
  // from ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()
  ImageCodecInfo jpegCodec = GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg");

  //create a collection of all parameters that we will pass to the encoder
  EncoderParameters encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(2);
  //set the quality and compression parameters for the codec
  encoderParams.Param[0] = qualityParam;
  encoderParams.Param[1] = compressionParam;
  //save the image using the codec and the parameters
  image.Save(path, jpegCodec, encoderParams);
}
```

In my website, users submit pictures that get scaled down to around 900x900 first (with GDI itself, to reduce the file size, which can be up to 4mb), and then are saved into disk.
The problem with this is that running it with the same System.Drawing.Image image parameter in my machine and in my Linode node yields:
1. In my machine, a 3.1mb hi-res image gets turned into a ~80kb image.
2. In my Linode, the very same image will yield a ~500kb image.

I would like to emphasize, first of all, that I run the very same web app in my computer for testing/developing that I run in my Linode. Also, I checked the versions of all the software installed in both machines (gentoo linux, by the way), and I got:
1. Mono: 2.10.5, same USE flags in both machines;
2. Apache 2.2.21-r1, some USE flags are a bit different (but shouldn't interfere);
3. Mod_mono 2.10, same USE flags in both machines;
4. libgdiplus 2.10, same USE flags at first, then tried enabling cairo in of the machines, with no change of results;
5. cairo 1.10.2-r1, the opengl flag has been enabled in my machine but not in Linode.

I cannot think of the reason why the behavior is SO different. The big difference is that my Linode is a 32 bit Linux 3.0.4 while my machine is a 64 bit Linux 2.6.39, although I think this shouldn't interfere either.

Any similar experiences or ideas, anyone?

Answer (score 2):

libgdiplus does not do it's own JPEG processing, it only includes a bit of glue code to map the GDI+ API to libjpeg. Also there are no 32/64 bits different code paths inside libgdiplus itself.

I would suspect some difference between the versions of libjpeg being used on your box versus the one on linode.

Comment: Oh my god! Forgot to mention the libjpeg version is the same on both as well!
The virtual/jpeg ebuild on both gentoo machines installed libjpeg-turbo 1.1.1

Comment: never heard of libjpeg-**turbo** but I still see it as the main *candidate* for the difference. A quick grep at the source might tell you if 32/64 bits code paths differs (e.g. optimizations). Otherwise fill a bug report to have someone else try this on another operating system (in case it's gentoo related) -> http://bugzilla.xamarin.com

Comment: thanks, I needed someone to tell me that it could be someone other than myself making the mistakes this time. I will see to this problem now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the version of your libjpeg on both machines? Perhaps that's the issue?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that, please check the comment on poupou's answer (same libjpeg)